# Getting list of checked checkbox values using ES6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

My checkboxes look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="abc" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="def" checked>
```

I know I can get all the values with

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

The ES6 equivalent using arrow functions I thought would be something like

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map((el) => el.value).get();
```

but all I get is an empty array.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JQuery's [`.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/)  passes a reference to the element in your callback's *second* argument. The first argument is an index.

You get an empty array because `.value` is `undefined` for the indices (numbers), and when you return `undefined` jQuery's `.map()` doesn't add an element to the result.

So:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map((i, el) => el.value).get();
```

(So the problem wasn't because you used an arrow function rather than a standard function.)